# Determinant of $(p(x_i-x_j))_{1 \leq i,j \leq n}$ for polynomial $p(x)$.

Tags: polynomials, determinant, algebraic-combinatorics

Let $p(x) = a_0 + a_1 x + \ldots + a_k x^k$ be a polynomial.
Can anything be said in general about the determinant $\mathrm{det}_{1 \leq i,j \leq n} (p(x_i-x_j))$ for a collection of variables $x_1,\ldots,x_n$?

It seems that for small $n,k$, the first order term in the determinant - which is itself a polynomial in the variables $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ - is a Vandermonde determinant.

Comment: Answering in part my own question: The determinant is clearly zero whenever $x_i = x_j$ for some $i,j$. It follows that the determinant is divisible by some power of the Vandermonde determinant $\prod_{1 \leq i < j \leq n} (x_j-x_i)$.